# SymmetricDS Embedded

Tags: database, jetty, synchronization, symmetricds

I'm trying to implement database synchronization using SymmetricDS. So far I am able sync database using standalone client and server.

Now I want to run SymmetricDS from java code:

```
SymmetricWebServer node = new SymmetricWebServer("symmmetric.properties");
node.setWebAppDir(webAppDir);
node.start(9090);
```

However program stuck:

```
INFO [19:21:58,768] SymmetricWebServer - About to start SymmetricDS web server on port 9090
INFO [19:21:58,816] Server - jetty-7.6.14.v20131031
INFO [19:21:58,973] StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO [19:21:58,996] ContextHandler - started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{.},../client/web/WEB-INF
INFO [19:21:59,058] AbstractConnector - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9090
INFO [19:21:59,064] SymmetricWebServer - Starting JMX HTTP console on port 9091
INFO [19:21:59,145] SymmetricWebServer - Joining the web server main thread
HttpAdaptor version 3.0.1 started on port 9091
```

How can I fix that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SymmetricWebServer node = new SymmetricWebServer("symmmetric.properties");
node.setWebAppDir(webAppDir);
node.setJoin(false);
node.start(9090);
```